# Line in sudoers.d not working

Tags: command-line, sudo, ubuntu-mate

The last line is not working when I use sudo geany.

```
andy ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/thunar
andy ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/geany
andy ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/andy/PEAZIP/peazip_portable-6.6.0.LINUX.x86_64.GTK2/peazip
```

Does it have to be in a bin directory?

Comment: You can check `/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples/sudoers` how to configure lines

Answer (score 1):

There is a property named `secure_path`:

> Path used for every command run from sudo. If you don't trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to
>                      use this.

so when you run:

```
sudo peazip
```

it look inside these paths:

```
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

You have to run your command like:

```
sudo /home/andy/PEAZIP/peazip_portable-6.6.0.LINUX.x86_64.GTK2/peazip
```

But don't do this, it's not safe. Anybody can change `peazip` file with a destructive binary and run it using `sudo` without having your password.

Comment: Can't they do that as well with thunar,etc ? I am the only one with access to my computer.

Comment: That's another problem and the answer is yes. if you allow anyone run a file manger using `sudo` without knowing the password, then they can do whatever they want to your system.

Comment: A general rule is that the easier you make it for you to do admin things, the easier you make it for a hacker to do more than you know how to and/or want them to.

Comment: I will keep those in mind. @Ravexina @ nobody special